# Windows 8 Ubuntu Installation

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

I'm currently attempting to install Ubuntu on my desktop via the desktop installer iso. Windows 8 is my current OS, could anyone help me install Ubuntu, as Windows 8 is stopping me from doing so?

Comment: hi, how are you attempting to do so? did you burn it to a dvd or put it on a usb, or are you trying to launch something from within windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the WUBI installer in Windows 8, I have had issues with the equivalent in Linux Mint. To install from a Live USB/DVD use these steps:

1. Download an ISO from [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (64 bit or 32 bit depending on your flavor)
2. Download a ISO burning program I recommend [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [Rufus.](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) Instructions for use can be found on both of their websites.
3. Burn the ISO to a USB medium or DVD using whatever program you wish.
4. BACK UP EVERYTHING!!! [These methods](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-safest-ways-to-backup-restore-your-files-in-windows-7-8/) work well.
5. Restart your computer and enter the BIOS by pressing the "System Setup" (or something along those lines) key. It is usually [DEL], [F2], or [F12] but it will say on your screen as your computer boots.
6. Under the "BOOT" section, change the boot order of your PC to prioritize your USB/DVD. Ensure that fast boot is turned off. If you can't find anything that talks about it, then it is already turned off. Exit the BIOS saving changes.
7. You will now boot onto your USB/DVD. Follow onscreen instructions from their. Should you wish to erase everything and install only Ubuntu select that option. Should you wish to Dual-boot between Windows 8 and Ubuntu, select "Something Else" and follow [these instructions.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) Should you wish to try Ubuntu without installing, select that option (Recommended).
8. Have fun, let me know if you have errors/problems/questions.